# How to show Month, Year, Date in separate input fields in react. Any npm package suggestion would be appreciated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-datepicker

I am using react date picker package in my current react project. I have date/month/year in a single input field. However I would like separate them into individual input fields.
Currently I have like this[image]

How ever I would like to display fields like this one [image]

I am also trying to implement this in react native.How to achieve this?